# Is a trading partner code list necessary for EDI parsing?

Tags: data-transfer, edi, x12

New to EDI, but trying to write a PoC EDI Parser for a client.

They've given me an x12 850 and an x12 315 file to serve as examples, but one of the things they're interested in is making the segment/data element headers human readable.

Ex:

```
N4*KOWLOON**99999*HK~
```

becomes

```
geographic_location: [KOWLOON, 99999, HK]
```

I've been searching online and have found a few different code lists for 850s ([1](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/XI/Description+of+EDI+850+Fields), [2](https://www.erico.com/public/library/edi/ERICO850_4010.pdf)) and 315s([3](https://www.aafes.com/Images/doingbusiness/315v43r1.pdf)), but I'm not sure if these correspond exactly to the lists used by the client.

I don't want to waste the client's time requesting unnecessary documents. How strict are these specifications, and is it worth getting the client's specific implementation here? If so, what exact documents will I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The X12 standard handles a number of vertical markets.  The code lists typically apply across those verticals, and some can be industry specific.  What I would recommend is looking at a Dictionary Viewer like the one found here: https://www.liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad/edi-dictionary-viewer/

Answer (score 1):

Requesting a list of locations is not only normal, it's recommended. The reason for using EDI is to reduce errors during production. There should be some sort data alignment process where all product and location data is matched on each trading partners end before going live.

Trying to guess what your trading partner will send you is exactly what you want to avoid.